# Do I need oauth for access token based authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have a Single Page Application for non-/mobile html5 browsers getting data from a RESTful HTTP API with asp.net web api. We use OWIN self hosting running in a windows service.

I do not want cookie based authentication. I would like to authenticate the user and give him a json based access token with its claims/permissions to edit/create/delete/show certains things in the UI.

I do not need external login provider. Our user will authenticate with username and password not their google email...

Now I askmyself should I go in direction thinktecture and identyserver, or asp.net identity or...OWIN and ExternalBearer authentication, I am lost here.

What would be your recommendation basing on my information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer is suitable for scenarios where you have multiple applications and want them to authenticate against a single STS, basically if you want SSO. The scenario you described is achieved in IdentityServer by OAuth. That is you define an application you wish to use IdentityServer to authenticate, and then create an OAuth client to get access tokens for accessing that application. If that's not the case then you're probably better off avoiding the complexity of introducing a 3rd party component to do that work. We're using IdentityServer to authenticate users of 3 different apps 2 SPAs and an MVC application. Also, you realy can't seperate OWIN and ASP.NET identity in this case. The OWIN middleware will give you the tokens and it will be using ASP.NET Identity as a user repository to authenticate users, so OWIN is just doing the job of providing tokens and using ASP.NET Identity to authenticate users.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading comment about asp.net identity or ...OWIN. Of course they depend together. We have only ONE application. "...a 3rd party component to do that work..." The 3rd party would be the asp.net identity then, right? And If I would have a separated admin site from the user site to run on separated server then you say identityserver would fit better?

Comment: No, the 3rd party would be IdentityServer. I'm basically saying that IdentityServer has its own learning curve and its documentation is nowhere near as abundant or complete as that of OWIN and ASP.NET Identity. If I was you I would go ahead and use ASP.NET Identity/OWIN, if you think you will have other applications in the future that you need to authenticate against that same database of users then use IdentityServer.

Comment: "if you think you will have other applications in the future that you need to authenticate against that same database of users then use IdentityServer. –" As I said before we have WILL have a separate admin/user site. When the admin or user login on each their site they will use of course the same database. Basing on this information where would be the concrete benefit of using identityServer vs. asp.net identity with owin?

Comment: Thanks for the overview which is a bummer... It does not answer my question actually just produces new questions... ;-) And if I would use identityServer I would wait for v3 this spring. I know v2 from a former company partly and its lots to setup...

Comment: I've already said that using Identity Server for the scenario you described is an overkill. [Just go ahead and use OWIN](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/). In summary IdentityServer is used when have many applications that you wish to authenticate in one place, SSO! It also gives you fine grained control over how you issue your tokens and what you put inside those tokens. Which you don't really seem to need.

Comment: Ok, but you have read this? "...authenticate the user and give him a json based access token with its claims/permissions..." Is this not enough fine grained control I would need?

Comment: Look at the G`rantResourceOwnerCredentials` method in the `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` class In the link I posted in the comment above. That answers your question, in case you don't catch on basically you can add whatever you want as a claim to the token, that's more than enough fine grained control.

Comment: OK thanks! I have checked the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider  class :)